# read_csv from url in pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm readind csv files from urls and append all csv files in one csv.
The final csv doesn't contain files from
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-regioni/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni-20201023.csv

to

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-regioni/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni-20201028.csv

all the others are ok.
I've tried everythings but all the csv seems good, I don't undertand why theese csv are not ok (from ...20201023.csv to ...20201028.csv)
If I read separately they works, so the issue seems in the pd.concatenate

Can you help please?

'''

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import read_csv
import requests
import io
from matplotlib import pyplot
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-regioni/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni-20200224.csv'

begin_date = date(2020, 10, 23)
delta3 = date.today() - begin_date
n = delta3.days
url_path_base = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/master/dati-regioni/dpc-covid19-ita-regioni-'
data_vec = []
urls = []
for x in range(n):
  el = datetime.today() - timedelta(x+1)
  data_vec.append(el.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
  url = url_path_base + el.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '.csv'
  urls.append(url)

ds = []
#print(urls)
for f in urls:
  s=requests.get(f).content
  ds.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8'))))
frame = pd.concat(ds, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
frame.set_index("data")
```

'''

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It would be helpful if you provided more detail on the error message(s) you receive, or what in the resulting dataframe is not looking right. Also you may wan to try to reduce the problem to a small example with small dataframes as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
Works for me as you've written your code except 
frame.set_index("data")
should be
frame.set_index("data", inplace=True)

# 21 datapoints per file
In [25]: frame['stato'].groupby(frame.index).count()
Out[25]:
data
2020-10-23T17:00:00    21
2020-10-24T17:00:00    21
2020-10-25T17:00:00    21
2020-10-26T17:00:00    21
2020-10-27T17:00:00    21
2020-10-28T17:00:00    21
2020-10-29T17:00:00    21
2020-10-30T17:00:00    21
2020-10-31T17:00:00    21
2020-11-01T17:00:00    21
2020-11-02T17:00:00    21
2020-11-03T17:00:00    21
2020-11-04T17:00:00    21
2020-11-05T17:00:00    21
2020-11-06T17:00:00    21
2020-11-07T17:00:00    21
2020-11-08T17:00:00    21
2020-11-09T17:00:00    21
2020-11-10T17:00:00    21
2020-11-11T17:00:00    21
Name: stato, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, so the only difference is inplace=True.